# lxml get text of elements with no tag

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I am using lxml library with python to parse a simple XML that prints the text of the next elements in this case HD as shown in the XML below

```
<BOOK>
   <HD>The Best Book Ever</HD>
   <HD>Table of Contents</HD>
   <EXTRACT>
      <TC>I. Introduction</TC>
      <TC>II. Summary</TC>
      <TC>III. Topic 1</TC>
      <TC>IV. Topic 2</TC>
   </EXTRACT>
   <HD>I. Introduction</HD>
   <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      <FTN>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus elit, suscipit eget</FTN>
   </p>
   <p>has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
   <HD>II. Summary</HD>
   <p>
       <FT>data 1</FT>
       data 2
      <FT>data 3</FT>
   </p>
    <p>
       <FT>data 4</FT>
       data 5
      <FT>data 6</FT>
   </p>
   <p>has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
   <HD>III. Topic 1</HD>
   <p>
      something
      <p>something else</p>
   </p>
   <HD>IV. Topic 2</HD>
   <p>
      something1
      <p>something else 1</p>
   </p>
   <p>
      something 2
      <p>something else 2</p>
   </p>
   <HD>V. Topic 3</HD>
   <p>
      something not to show up
      <p>because not in EXTRACT as TC</p>
   </p>
</BOOK>
```

my python code looks as shown below where it's supposed to print all the contents next to HD tag

```
import os
from lxml import etree

file_name = 'demofile2.xml'
full_file_name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('', file_name))

def load_local_file(filename):
    dom = etree.parse(filename)

    #get all content of elements after HD tag
    TOCsHD = dom.getroot().findall('HD')
    for hd in TOCsHD:
        text = hd.text
        print(text)
        for x in hd.getnext().iter():
            print(x.text)
            print(x.tail)
        print("------------------------------")


load_local_file(full_file_name)
```

My output is shown below. As you can see, II. Summary for example is not printing data 4, data 5, data 6. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you so much!

```
The Best Book Ever
Table of Contents

   
------------------------------
Table of Contents

      

   
I. Introduction

      
II. Summary

      
III. Topic 1

      
IV. Topic 2

   
------------------------------
I. Introduction

      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      

   
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus elit, suscipit eget

   
------------------------------
II. Summary

       

    
data 1

       data 2
      
data 3

   
------------------------------
III. Topic 1

      something
      

   
something else

   
------------------------------
IV. Topic 2

      something1
      

   
something else 1

   
------------------------------
V. Topic 3

      something not to show up
      


because not in EXTRACT as TC

   
------------------------------
```

Comment: What would be the desired output?

Comment: I need it to print all the content of the sibling tags of HD. it's only printing text from the next first element only

Comment: Please do not robo-approve in reviews. This edit was in no way approvable: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31439483

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but guess what you need probably is [`itersiblings`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itersiblings):

```py
import os
from lxml import etree

file_name = 'demofile2.xml'
full_file_name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('', file_name))

def load_local_file(filename):
    dom = etree.parse(filename)

    #get all content of elements after HD tag
    TOCsHD = dom.getroot().findall('HD')
    for hd in TOCsHD:
      print("Siblings of: " + hd.text)
      theIter = hd.itersiblings()
      for x in theIter:
          print(x.tag, "".join(x.itertext()).strip().replace("\n", ""), sep=": ")
      print("------------------------------")

load_local_file(full_file_name)
```

I am not sure this would be the result you are seeking, but if you are interested in the sibling of the tags, this function would work.

##### Output

```
Siblings of: The Best Book Ever
HD: Table of Contents
EXTRACT: I. Introduction      II. Summary      III. Topic 1      IV. Topic 2
HD: I. Introduction
p: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus elit, suscipit eget
p: has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
HD: II. Summary
p: data 1       data 2      data 3
p: data 4       data 5      data 6
p: has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
HD: III. Topic 1
p: something      something else
HD: IV. Topic 2
p: something1      something else 1
p: something 2      something else 2
HD: V. Topic 3
p: something not to show up      because not in EXTRACT as TC
------------------------------
Siblings of: Table of Contents
EXTRACT: I. Introduction      II. Summary      III. Topic 1      IV. Topic 2
HD: I. Introduction
p: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus elit, suscipit eget
p: has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
HD: II. Summary
p: data 1       data 2      data 3
p: data 4       data 5      data 6
p: has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
HD: III. Topic 1
p: something      something else
HD: IV. Topic 2
p: something1      something else 1
p: something 2      something else 2
HD: V. Topic 3
p: something not to show up      because not in EXTRACT as TC
------------------------------
Siblings of: I. Introduction
p: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam purus elit, suscipit eget
p: has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
HD: II. Summary
p: data 1       data 2      data 3
p: data 4       data 5      data 6
p: has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
HD: III. Topic 1
p: something      something else
HD: IV. Topic 2
p: something1      something else 1
p: something 2      something else 2
HD: V. Topic 3
p: something not to show up      because not in EXTRACT as TC
------------------------------
Siblings of: II. Summary
p: data 1       data 2      data 3
p: data 4       data 5      data 6
p: has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
HD: III. Topic 1
p: something      something else
HD: IV. Topic 2
p: something1      something else 1
p: something 2      something else 2
HD: V. Topic 3
p: something not to show up      because not in EXTRACT as TC
------------------------------
Siblings of: III. Topic 1
p: something      something else
HD: IV. Topic 2
p: something1      something else 1
p: something 2      something else 2
HD: V. Topic 3
p: something not to show up      because not in EXTRACT as TC
------------------------------
Siblings of: IV. Topic 2
p: something1      something else 1
p: something 2      something else 2
HD: V. Topic 3
p: something not to show up      because not in EXTRACT as TC
------------------------------
Siblings of: V. Topic 3
p: something not to show up      because not in EXTRACT as TC
------------------------------
```

Note that you need to use `itertext` as well in order to get all the text inside of all tags. For example, there are a few `p` tags that have inner tags inside them. If you want to have the text value of these `p` tags, you will need to apply `itertext` in order to get the inner text. You can gain insight into the process by looking at the line with `"".join(x.itertext()).strip().replace("\n", "")`.

Comment: ok i tried that and it did not print all the content

Comment: for example II. Summary HD did not print any of the first 2 p tags elements except the last one. I am not sure why

Comment: @RonnyK I think the code works. Because I get all of the `p` tags that are siblings for the II. Summary. Let me edit the answer and share the result with you.

Comment: @RonnyK Do you mean the `p`'s which have no text in front of them?

Comment: yes, why is that not being printed? thanks

Comment: @RonnyK Oh, I see. That is not a problem related to sibling function. I will explain it in my answer.

Comment: I ended up converting the whole XML to string and used regex to get all my data because I won't know how many elements are inside another